# Use domains instead of ports for multiple Docker containers

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm working on creating Docker environment for multiple websites. I've decided to have for each domain separate `docker-compose.yml` file with multiple containers. At the moment I have something like this:

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  volumes:
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/html/test-laravel-project-2/:/usr/share/nginx/html/test-laravel-project-2/
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/nginx-conf/conf.d2/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/nginx-log/:/var/log/nginx
  ports:
    - "8088:80"
  working_dir: /usr/share/nginx/html/test-laravel-project-2/
  links:
    - php
    - db
  container_name: lara.web
  environment:  
    - VIRTUAL_HOST='l2.app'
    - VIRTUAL_NETWORK='nginx-proxy'
  expose:
    - 8088
php:
  build: ../dockerfiles/
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-php7-fpm
  volumes:
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/html/test-laravel-project-2/:/usr/share/nginx/html/test-laravel-project-2/
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/php-config/:/usr/local/etc/php/
  working_dir: /usr/share/nginx/html/
  links:
    - db
  container_name: lara.php
db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
    MYSQL_DATABASE:
    MYSQL_USER: 
    MYSQL_PASSWORD:   
  expose:
     - 3306
  volumes:
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/mysql2/:/var/lib/mysql/
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/mysql-log2/:/var/log/mysql/
  ports:
    - "33062:3306"
  container_name: lara.db
```

This is working fine, but I've wanted to use domain for this because at the moment I need to use 8088 port like so: `http://192.168.99.100:8088`. Obviously I can in above config use `80:80` mapping but let's assume I want to use 8088 port (because for multiple sites I will need to use different port for each website).

And now the problem - how can I use domain instead of IP with port? I've added to my Windows (I'm using Windows as OS) `l2.app` with mapping to `192.168.99.100`, but I still need to use it like this: `http://l2.app:8088`.

I've also tried `nginx-proxy` like this:

```
docker pull jwilder/nginx-proxy
docker-compose up -d
docker run -d -p 80:8088 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

but when I try to access website using `http://l2.app` I'm getting `503` and obviously when I'm using `http://l2.app:8088` everything is fine.

I assume I probably misconfigured something with port mapping for `nginx-proxy` but have no clue in which place the mapping is incorrect. Could you please give me advice for this?

Comment: I think you need to start the `nginx-proxy` container first, and then `docker-compose up`. Also the port mapping for `nginx-proxy` should be 80:80. Although I think there may be further issue with this setup on Windows, as Docker runs inside a VM on Windows, so right now you point `l2.app` to 192.168.99.100, but `nginx-proxy` will point `l2.app` to the internal ip of the container within the VM. I haven't tested this but I think it may not work.

Comment: @warmoverflow I'm almost sure I was also trying as you wrote but I'll try again as soon as I'll have my PC around

Comment: @warmoverflow I've done it - without success. I've also tried changing in `expose` to `80` but it also doesn't help at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easier than I thought. Here are the steps through command line, but you should be able to create a corresponding `docker-compose.yml` file based on this. You don't need port mapping for the app containers if it runs on 80 by default (the proxy will know how to forward traffic to each container's 80 port, so you don't need to map them!)

1. Edit your Windows hosts file to point the domains to 192.168.99.100

On Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7/8/10, the file location is `C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts`. Add the following lines

```
192.168.99.100 myapp1.com
192.168.99.100 myapp2.com
```

2. Start `nginx-proxy` container first

Note that the double slash before `var`. You may only need a single slash depending on the terminal you are using. Try for yourself.

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v //var/run/docker/sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

3. Start your `app1` or `app2` container

You can start more containers with the same command, just change the domain and image name

```
docker run -d -e VIRTUAL_HOST=myapp1.com myapp1
docker run -d -e VIRTUAL_HOST=myapp2.com myapp2
```

4. In your web browser, open `http://myapp1.com` or `http://myapp2.com`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I haven't tried it yet but I'm using `docker-compose.yml` and run containers like so `docker-compose up -d` and you showed the method with `docker run`. Which image should I use and how can I link them without using `docker-compose` ?

Comment: I believe that if you run nginx-proxy with 80:80 first, then run you compose file next (but remove the port mapping and expose command for web) it will just work. If not, try also remove VIRTUAL_NETWORK

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work. there is no `myapp1` image because I have my containers names in `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: You don't need to change anything other than remove the `ports` and `expose` section in your `web` container part of the yml file. Run `nginx-proxy` first, then when you run `docker-compose up`, since you defined `VIRTUAL_HOST` in your compose file, the proxy will know how to forward `l2.app` to your container.